# React Native app crashing -> AsyncStorage used differently between builds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I made a React Native app and deployed it to both Apple and Google Play stores. We are up to build 63, but AsyncStorage was changed in build 58. So, when someone updates our app from 58 to any higher build, it crashes because it tries to access something that isn't there. Here is an example of how it's used differently:

We have a 'userType' that guides the app (from App.js) as to which login/home screen to send it (via react-navigation).

```
const userType = await AsyncStorage.getItem(AppConfig.CURRENT_USER_TYPE)
```

We have more instances of this, but I assume this will be a succinct enough example.

Prior to version 58, we only had one dashboard, so the userType was not an issue.

I thought of the idea of logging the user out whenever they update their app, but that would only work for future versions, as I can't retroactively change the code in build 58.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: So your app is crashing because there is a bug where it doesn't handle when the data isn't in `AsyncStorage`?

Comment: Yes. But only if the user is already logged in when they update. If not, the userType is stored during login. When a user updates their app, it reloads the app and starts at App.js (not the dashboard) and checks if the AUTH_TOKEN is stored. If so, it loads the userType from AsyncStorage and directs the user to the 'patient' or 'caregiver' dashboard. Since the new userType can only be decoded from the InviteToken (which the app doesn't use on subsequent reloads) or stored during login, the userType is nowhere to be found in AsyncStorage, since version 58 doesn't decode or store the userType.

Comment: I dont think the AsyncStorage memory persists across app versions. Kinda depends on how your update works. If the app doesn't handle it, then it doesn't handle it. Not a whole lot you can do, except fix it, make the other versions invalid, make them update to the newest version that has the fix and wont crash when the value is missing